# Android: Bold Button Text

Tags: android, button, bold, typeface

I have a button in my application. the text in the button goes as "`Type: Location`" something like that.

I'm wondering whether its possible to change the text on the button as "**Type**: Location"

i.e Bold the text partially on the button??

Thanks for yoru time in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply put your string in strings.xml and change it like this,

```
 <string name="hello"><b>Hello</b> World, fh!</string>
```

and set this text to your button like this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
```

Sometimes the above approach will not be helpful when you might have to use Dynamic Text. So at that case [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) comes into action.

```
  String tempString="Copyright";
  Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
  spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
  button.setText(spanString);
```

Comment: Don't forget add android:textAllCaps="false" (it doesn't work without that thing)

Answer (score 32):

we have a more better choice like this :`android:textStyle="bold"`
android api support bold

Comment: this will bold the whole text in the button :(

Comment: I ask my master ,he say that Html.fromHtml is better and more easlier control.

Answer (score 4):

You can set it using `Html.fromHtml()` and give as a string, a string resource with HTML elements. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Using spans:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("Type: your type here!");
StyleSpan boldStyle = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
builder.setSpan(boldStyle, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use basic markup directory in strings, e.g.

`"<b>Type</b>: Location"`

See [Styling with HTML markup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 1):

If want to set text programmatically then use this method

**Button**

First you have to set button's property in XML

```
android:textAllCaps="false" // very important without this property might be it won't show effect

public SpannableString setSpanableString(String textString, int start, int end){

    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(textString);
    spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, end, 0);

    return spanString;
}


Button btn; // get your button reference here

String text = "Hi, Dharmbir";
btn.setText(setSpanableString(text, 4, text.length));// set here your index
```

**TextView**

```
TextView tv; // get your TextView reference here

String text = "Hi, Dharmbir";
tv.setText(setSpanableString(text, 4, text.length));
```

**Output**

Hi, **Dharmbir**